# Sendmail local domain is hosted externally e-mail fails :(

Tags: sendmail

I have sendmail which works great sending to external domains, but for its own internal domain it tries to deliver mail locally instead of externally based on the MX records. Is there a way to fix this?

I have looked at other posts, but haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Do you run a DNS server locally? And do you have an MX record local and with ISP?

Comment: this was obviously not an answer, I will adjust momentarily

Comment: I do not run a dns server locally for domain.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sendmail : ignore local delivery](https://serverfault.com/questions/239261/sendmail-ignore-local-delivery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may benefit from "nullclient" configuration of sendmail. Just put the following in your /etc/mail/sendmail.mc:

```
include(`/usr/share/sendmail-cf/m4/cf.m4')dnl
VERSIONID(`nullclient setup')dnl
OSTYPE(`linux')dnl
FEATURE(`nullclient',`your.mail.server.address.or.name')dnl
```

It will forward everything to an external mail server except mail addressed to 'root' (at least this is how it works on Centos).

Comment: This didn't work for me on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, maybe the domainame is in the /etc/mail/local-host-names file? and thus gets interpreted local.

Comment: I tried that too, I removed the domain and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I just [answered](https://serverfault.com/questions/239261/sendmail-ignore-local-delivery) this in another question.

Comment: Maybe it should be converted to a comment, but it is in-network linking.